# Automatic awaiting on coroutines when actual values are needed?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Assume I want to implement the following using asyncio:

```
def f(): 
    val1 = a()  # a() takes 1 sec
    val2 = b()  # b() takes 3 sec
    val3 = c(val1, val2)  # c() takes 1 sec, but must wait for a() and b() to finish
    val4 = d(val1)  # d() takes 1 sec, but must wait for a() to finish
```

all functions a, b, c, d are asynchronous and could potentially run in parallel. The optimized way to run this would be: 1) run a() and b() in parallel. 2) when a() is done, run d(). 3) when a() and b() are done, run c(). Everything together should take 4 seconds.

I find that implementing that with asyncio is not ideal:

```
import time
import asyncio

async def a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def b():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def c(val1, val2):
    await val2
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def d(val1):
    await val1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def f():
    val1 = a()
    val2 = b()
    val3 = c(val1, val2)
    val4 = d(val1)
    return await asyncio.gather(val3, val4)

t1 = time.time()
await f()
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)  # This will be 4 seconds indeed
```

The above implementation works, but the main flow is that I need to know that a() finishes before b(), in order to await val1 in d() and not await it in c(). In other words, given a (possibly complex) execution graph, I have to know which functions finish before others, in order to place the "await" statement in the right place. It I await the same coroutine in two places, I get an exception.

My question is the following: is there a mechanism in asyncio (or other python module), that awaits on coroutines automatically, just when they are needed to be resolved to actual values? I know that such mechanism is implemented in other parallel execution mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways how to do it. One possibility is to use synchronization primitives, such as [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event). For example:

```py
import time
import asyncio


val1 = None
val2 = None

event_a = None
event_b = None


async def a():
    global val1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  # some computation
    val1 = 1
    event_a.set()


async def b():
    global val2
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    val2 = 100
    event_b.set()


async def c():
    await event_a.wait()
    await event_b.wait()

    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return val1 + val2


async def d():
    await event_a.wait()

    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return val1 * 2


async def f():
    global event_a
    global event_b

    event_a = asyncio.Event()
    event_b = asyncio.Event()

    out = await asyncio.gather(a(), b(), c(), d())
    assert out[2] == 101
    assert out[3] == 2


async def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    await f()
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2 - t1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
4.0029356479644775
```

---

Another option is to split computation to more coroutines, for example:

```py
import time
import asyncio


async def a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  # some computation
    return 1


async def b():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 100


async def c(val1, val2):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return val1 + val2


async def d(val1):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return val1 * 2


async def f():
    async def task1():
        params = await asyncio.gather(a(), b())  # <-- run a() and b() in parallel
        return await c(*params)

    async def task2():
        return await d(await a())

    out = await asyncio.gather(task1(), task2())
    assert out[0] == 101
    assert out[1] == 2


async def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    await f()
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2 - t1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
4.00294041633606
```

Comment: I think the first solution is the only valid one though. I think in the second solution, you are running a() twice (that's why you are not getting an exception for waiting on the same coroutine twice).

Comment: Is there some way to await on the same coroutine in two different places? Looks like using events can do exactly that, but I wonder if there's some built in mechanism instead of setting an event for each coroutine